# Infinite recursion when generating n-ary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree

I would like to build a tree similar to the one below.
[image: GP Solution Tree]

However, it appears that the children of each node are not being set correctly and I am unsure why.

For background, I am trying to implement the [Boolean 6-Multiplexer Problem](https://www.gene-expression-programming.com/Problem05.asp) using Genetic Programming (GP). A `Function` is an operator that would have its children as input. For example, `IF` represents the operation: `if children[0], return children[1], else return children[2]`. A `Terminal` is basically a leaf node of the tree, which has a value and does not have children.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val: int = None, children: "list[Node]" = []):
        self.val = val
        self.children = children

    def add_child(self, node):
        self.children.append(node)

    def __str__(self, level=0) -> str:
        ret = "\t" * level + self.__repr__() + f"({self.val})" + "\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__str__(level + 1)

        return ret

    def required_children_count(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def eval(self) -> int:
        pass


class Terminal(Node):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Terminal"

    def required_children_count(self):
        return 0

    def eval(self):
        return self.val


class Function(Node):
    pass


class AND(Function):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "AND"

    def required_children_count(self):
        return 2

    def eval(self):
        return self.children[0].eval() and self.children[1].eval()


class OR(Function):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "OR"

    def required_children_count(self):
        return 2

    def eval(self):
        return self.children[0].eval() or self.children[1].eval()


class NOT(Function):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "NOT"

    def required_children_count(self):
        return 1

    def eval(self):
        return not self.children[0].eval()


class IF(Function):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "IF"

    def required_children_count(self):
        return 3

    def eval(self):
        return (
            self.children[1].eval()
            if self.children[0].eval()
            else self.children[2].eval()
        )


class GP:
    def __init__(
        self,
        terminals: "list[Type[Terminal]]" = [],  # TODO: figure out this struct
        functions: "list[Type[Function]]" = [],
        solutions={},
        pop_size=100,
        pm=0.05,
        pc=0.4,
        max_depth=3,
    ):
        self.pop_size = pop_size
        self.terminals = terminals
        self.functions = functions
        self.population = []
        self.max_depth = max_depth

    def generate_full_tree_helper(self, node: Node, depth=0):
        for i in range(node.required_children_count()):
            if depth == self.max_depth:
                node.children.append(Terminal(4))
            else:
                new_node = random.choice(self.functions)()
                self.generate_full_tree_helper(new_node, depth + 1)
                node.add_child(new_node)
                print(
                    f"depth: {depth}, node: {node.__repr__()}, children: {len(node.children)}"
                )

    def generate_full_tree(self):
        head = random.choice(self.functions)()
        self.generate_full_tree_helper(head)
        return head

    # ...


# (a0, a1) -> (d0, d1, d2, d3)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gp = GP(functions=[AND, OR, NOT, IF])
    gp.generate_full_tree()
```

Which will print:

```
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 6
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 10
depth: 1, node: NOT, children: 11
depth: 0, node: IF, children: 12
depth: 2, node: NOT, children: 15
depth: 1, node: NOT, children: 16
depth: 0, node: IF, children: 17
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 20
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 23
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 25
depth: 1, node: NOT, children: 26
depth: 0, node: IF, children: 27
```

When I would expect it to print (due to the required children count of each `Function`):

```
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 1, node: NOT, children: 1
depth: 0, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 2, node: NOT, children: 1
depth: 1, node: NOT, children: 1
depth: 0, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 2, node: IF, children: 3
depth: 1, node: NOT, children: 1
depth: 0, node: IF, children: 3
```

If I try and `print(gp.generate_full_tree())`, I get the following, which I assume is due to the children being in a cycle somehow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelvytlingam/Development/ECE457A/a4/q3/q3.py", line 99, in <module>
    print(gp.generate_full_tree())
  File "/Users/michaelvytlingam/Development/ECE457A/a4/q3/functions.py", line 13, in __str__
    ret += child.__str__(level + 1)
  File "/Users/michaelvytlingam/Development/ECE457A/a4/q3/functions.py", line 13, in __str__
    ret += child.__str__(level + 1)
  File "/Users/michaelvytlingam/Development/ECE457A/a4/q3/functions.py", line 13, in __str__
    ret += child.__str__(level + 1)
  [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
  File "/Users/michaelvytlingam/Development/ECE457A/a4/q3/functions.py", line 11, in __str__
    ret = "\t" * level + self.__repr__() + f"({self.val})" + "\n"
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I normally have a pretty good understanding of recursion, but for some reason, this has been stumping me for quite some time now. If I were to guess, I would say the `node.add_child(new_node)` line doesn't do what I think it does. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your issue is probably that the `children` list of each node is shared, since they're all using the default list. But you're also using a mutable default argument for `terminals` and `functions` in `GP.__init__`, so some of the issue might arise there instead.

Comment: Yes, this seemed to be caused by the default list. I defaulted `children` to `None` instead and modified the program to acommodate. You learn something new everyday, thank you for your help @Blckknght!